# Are Desktop Environment and Desktop Managers same thing on Linux, if yes how to know which desktop manager I'm using from my terminal?

Tags: 14.04, command-line, desktop-environments

Are Desktop Environment and Desktop Managers same thing on Linux, if yes how to know which desktop manager I'm using from my terminal?  Is task manager also the same desktop manager?

Comment: Just type `$DESKTOP_SESSION`

Comment: Also: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116539/how-to-detect-the-desktop-environment-in-a-bash-script